# MongoDB count() versus countDocuments()

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am using MongoDB and more specifically Mongoose.  I've recently been getting rid of some deprecation warnings from updating mongo and mongoose.

Some of my queries might as shown:

```
const count = await Badge.find(query).count().exec()
```

I have since changed this to

```
const count = Badge.find(query).countDocuments().exec()
```

and viola the depracation warning is gone.  However, reading the documentation at MongoDB it seems that it should be written like this:

```
const count = Badge.countDocuments(query)
```

All of the above return the exact same thing.  Obviously the latter two are the ones I want because of the depracation of `count()`.

What is the difference between the second two and should I prefer one over the other?

Comment: What does driver documentation say is the correct usage?

Comment: @D.SM it says `db.collection.countDocuments()` is the correct usage as of Mongo v4.0 on.  However, through testing I noticed `db.collection.find().countDocuments()` also works.  But I am unsure whether there is implication of using the later that I'm not thinking of.  Trying to understand the difference.

Comment: Link to the docs describing countdocuments. If both usages are documented, either one is valid. If only one is documented, the other one shouldn't be used even if it happens to work at the present time.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `db.collection.find` method returns a *cursor*. The [cursor.count()](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/method/cursor.count/) method on the cursor counts the number of documents referenced by a cursor. This is same as the `db.collection.count()`.

Both these methods (the `cursor.count()` and `db.collection.count()`) are deprecated as of MongoDB v4.0.  From the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/method/db.collection.count/#db.collection.count):

> MongoDB drivers compatible with the 4.0 features deprecate their
> respective cursor and collection count() APIs in favor of new APIs for
> countDocuments() and estimatedDocumentCount(). For the specific API
> names for a given driver, see the driver documentation.

> Avoid using the db.collection.count() method without a query predicate
> since without the query predicate, the method returns results based on
> the collection’s metadata, which may result in an approximate count.

[db.collection.countDocuments(query)](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/method/db.collection.countDocuments/) returns the count of documents that match the query for a collection or view. This is the method you need to use to count the number of documents in your collection.

> All of the above return the exact same thing.

Yes, most of the times. Only, the `countDocuments` returns the actual count of the documents. The other methods return counts based upon the collection's meta data.

If you want to use `db.collection.count`, use it with a *query predicate*, and this will return the exact count of the documents (but, note that this method is deprecated).

Comment: I guess my real question is whether `db.collection.find.countDocuments()` is fine to use? 
 It works perfectly but documentation says `db.oollection.countDocuments()` as usage.

Comment: Mongoose has its own API about `db.collection.find.countDocuments()` (and this is not available in mongo shell). The usage is different. See Mongoose's [Query.prototype.countDocuments()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-countDocuments) and [Query](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html).

Answer (score 7):

`db.collection.count()` does not count the actual number of documents, it returns results based on the collection’s metadata, which may result in an approximate count.

See [db.collection.count()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/index.html)

For proper distinction MonogDB introduced `countDocuments()` and `estimatedDocumentCount()` methods.

Answer (score 0):

What I remember the count() method was used for mongo shell. and if you want to implement this on nodejs you must use the countDocuments() based on the nodejs driver.

also, according to mongodb documentation db.collection.count()

> Returns the count of documents that would match a find() query for the collection or view. The db.collection.count() method does not perform the find() operation but instead counts and returns the number of results that match a query.

[Link about db.collection.count()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/)