# MongoDB Master/Slave Counts

Tags: mongodb, database-replication, master-slave, replicaset

I have a query. So i have a MongoDB master/slave setup running and i want to take the count of a particular collection in both DB's. If i use ***db.collection.count()***, i get different results for master/slave db's. However, i found somewhere that i should be using the following query:
***db.collection.find({_id:{ $gt: MinKey, $lt:MaxKey} }, {_id:1}).itcount().***
Can anyone please explain the difference between the two queries and whether the difference in counts using the normal count query is normal?

Comment: check first replication slave status whether they are in sync or not during query

rs.printSlaveReplicationInfo()

Comment: I ran the rs.printSlaveReplicationInfo() and the result was syncedTo: Mon Mar 15 2021 05:50:02 GMT+0000 (UTC)
 0 secs (0 hrs) behind the primary

Comment: Master/Slave replication does not exist anymore in MongoDB, it was removed in version 4.0. Successor is `printSecondaryReplicationInfo()`

Comment: Regardless, output is the same

Comment: What is the version of MongoDB you are using? Also, see this post [MongoDB count() versus countDocuments()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65282889/mongodb-count-versus-countdocuments/65286914#65286914).

Comment: My MongoDB version is 3.4.24......countDocuments() ain't available in this version.....also the difference in counts is in only two collections....rest the counts with the normal count query are  same.....However these two collections is where the bulk of the operations take place...rest are seldom updated...

Comment: can you stop writes for moment on heavy write collections and check?

Comment: No I cannot stop the writes.....its a production server

Answer (score 0):

"master/slave" is not correct MongoDB terminology for any supported server version.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/65285380/9540925, and then read the linked MongoDB documentation, for the explanation of the differences.

Comment: I get your point......can you please suggest what the itcount() query above is all about?