# Mongo .find() returning duplicate documents (with same _id) (!)

Tags: mongodb

Mongo appears to be returning duplicate documents for the same query, i.e. it returns more documents than there are unique `_id`s in the returned documents:

```
lobby-brain> count_iterated = 0; ids = {}
{}
lobby-brain> db.the_collection.find({
    'a_boolean_key': true 
}).forEach((el) => {
    count_iterated += 1; 
    ids[el._id] = (ids[el._id]||0) + 1;
})
lobby-brain> count_iterated
278
lobby-brain> Object.keys(ids).length
251
```

That is, the number of unique _id returned is 251 -- but there were 278 documents returned by the cursor.

Investigating further:

```
lobby-brain> ids
{
  '60cb8cb92c909a974a96a430': 1,
  '61114dea1a13c86146729f21': 1,
  '6111513a1a13c861467d3dcf': 1,
  ...
  '61114c491a13c861466d39cf': 2,
  '61114bcc1a13c861466b9f8e': 2,
  ...
}
lobby-brain> db.the_collection.find({
    _id: ObjectId("61114c491a13c861466d39cf")
}).forEach((el) => print("foo"));
foo

>
```

That is, there aren't actually duplicate documents with the same `_id` -- it's just an issue with the `.find()`.

I tried restarting the database, and rebuilding an index involving 'a_boolean_key', with the same results.

I've never seen this before and this seems impossible... what is causing this and how can I fix it?

**Version info:**

```
Using MongoDB:          5.0.5
Using Mongosh:          1.0.4
```

It is a stand-alone database, no replica set or sharding or anything like that.

**Further Info**

One thing to note is, there is a compound index with a_boolean_key as the first index, and a datetime field as the second. The boolean key is rarely updated on the database (~once/day), but the datetime field is frequently updated.

Maybe these updates are causing the duplicate return values?

Update Feb 15, 2022: I added a [Mongo JIRA task here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/WT-8844).

Comment: See [MongoDB count() versus countDocuments()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65282889/mongodb-count-versus-countdocuments/65286914#65286914) - to get an accurate count use `countDocuments()`.

Comment: The issue isn't with `.count()` actually -- take a look at the full example. But in any case, both  .count() and .countDocuments() return the correct count, which is 251. I've edited the example to not use .count() at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Louis Williams over at [Mongo JIRA](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-63667?focusedCommentId=4356610&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-4356610), this is not a bug but expected behavior.

Learn something new every day!

Answer (score 1):

Try checking if you store indexes for `a_boolean_key` field.

> When performing a `count`, MongoDB can return the count using only the
> index

So, maybe you don't have indexes for all documents, so `count` method result is not equal to your manual count.

Comment: That's interesting -- but see the updated example, even if I don't use .count(), I still see the same issue - the number of unique _id in what's returned is less than the total number of documents returned.

Comment: Do you have access to the database? What is actual number of documents there, and do you really have multiple documents with same `_id`?

Comment: I do -- the correct number is 251. It doesn't look like there are actual duplicates in the database. I edited the OP with more info.