# How do I get number of documents in collection?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to get the number of of documents in mongodb's collection, but I don't know realy how.
With this code:

```
function countDocuments(collectionName) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            functions.dbConnect().then((conn) => {
                conn.database.collection(collectionName).countDocuments((err, data) => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                        reject(err);
                    }
                    resolve(data);
                });
            });
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    });
}

//(async function() {
    const result = /*await*/ countDocuments('imuCollection');
    console.log('result = ' + result);
//}) ();
```

I'm getting

```
result = [object Promise]
```

And with this code:

```
function countDocuments(collectionName) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            functions.dbConnect().then((conn) => {
                conn.database.collection(collectionName).countDocuments((err, data) => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                        reject(err);
                    }
                    resolve(data);
                });
            });
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    });
}

(async function() {
    const result = await countDocuments('imuCollection');
    console.log('result = ' + result);
}) ();
```

I'm getting the result:

```
result = 30155393
```

The problem with these 2 code snippets is that the code does not return to the shell.
Is there a way to do it simpler?
(the dbConnect() code is working).

Comment: db. collection. count() will help you to count the number of total number of documents in the collection.

Comment: Yes, with count() it is faster, but I don't know why it is blocking.

Comment: The `count` result is from collection's meta data, where as `countDocuments` result in exact document count ( see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65282889/mongodb-count-versus-countdocuments ).