# Storing query count for all queries

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm looking for a way to cache count() for every unique query I make over every collection. So that the count can quickly be retrieved.

Is there a best practice for where the data should be stored?

For example

`db.getCollection("col1").find(query1).count()` --> 890

`db.getCollection("col1").find(query2).count()` --> 22100

`db.getCollection("col2").find(query3).count()` --> 4

`db.getCollection("col2").find(query4).count()` --> 901

Would a special collection with all queries and their respective counts be a good idea or should I save it together in each collection etc?

Comment: To get the exact count of documents you can use the `db.collection.countDocuments({})`. But, you can get the count from meta-data and this may not be the exact count. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65282889/mongodb-count-versus-countdocuments/65286914#65286914 . That said, the number of documents in a collection can change as inserts and deletes happen.

Answer (score 0):

Using $**count**:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   // Other stages here
   { $count: "Total" }
])
```

For getting 1000 records this takes on average 2 ms and is the fastest way.

Using .**itcount**():

```
db.collection.aggregate([...]).itcount();
```

For getting 1000 records this takes on average 14 ms.