# How to count records in the mongodb shell?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I can get a list of all the records, using `db.collectionName.find()`, but how would I be able to find a count of all the records?

Answer (score -2):

You can use `db.myCollection.count()`

Or, if you wanted to count records that matched your JSON, you could use:

```
db.myCollection.count({ a: 'b' })
```

Comment: You have additional info at: [MongoDB count() versus countDocuments()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65282889/mongodb-count-versus-countdocuments)

Comment: the question and the answer at the same time?

Comment: @DerekMenénedez Sharing my knowledge, Q&A-style